# Wordpress plugin causes page to not load/does not display requested data

Tags: wordpress

Here is a plugin I'm working on. It's task is to parse a CSV file and displaying it as an HTML table on a wordpress page where it's shortcode is present.

When I activate the plugin and visit a page that contains it's shortcode, the page will not load, my browsers (FireFox, Chrome) attempt to load the page and cannot, I don't even get a WSoD; I also check my server's stats when this happens and notice that CPU usage is at 85% which is very abnormal.

Once the plugin is deactivated, CPU usage returns to normal (usually 0-14%) and the page containing the plugin's shortcode will load (but obviously won't load the data requested by the shortcode).

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this.

I have even tried using examples I've found of known working scripts that perform a similar task, and have experienced the same results every time.

The CSV file it's trying to open was generated by Excel 2003, and the CSV file is in the plugin folder.

Here are the contents of the CSV file:

```
Make, Model, Origin, Color, Miles, Options
Chevy, Tahoe, Delaware, Black, 10000, LX
Ford, F150, Texas, Red, 5000, S
Chevy, Corvette, Utah, Red, 12000, SE
Mazda, Miata, Florida, Blue, 90000, LX
```

---

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: CSV 3
   Plugin URI: 
   Description: Displays CSV files as HTML tables
   Version: 1.0
   Author: Kreation
   Author URI: 
   License:
   */

add_shortcode( "csv", "open_csv_file");

function open_csv_file() {
$file = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . 'Book1.csv' );
    $handle = fopen("$file", "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    $color = $data[3];
    $options = $data[5];
    echo('<table>');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $color = $data[3];
        $options = $data[5];
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr data-color="' . $color . '" data-options="' . $options . '">');
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');
        }
        echo('</tr>');
    }
    echo("</table>");
    fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is present in the location, try using the plugin_dir_path for the exact directory location. Secondly on every refresh it is extracting all the data in the file, which i guess is not what you want. So you should try to save it in a database and time cache it.

Comment: `$file = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . 'Book1.csv' );`

Would this work?

Comment: yes if its in the root of your plugin, i.e www.yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/yourplugin/book1.csv. just change the parameters and open it in your browser to verify the file is present

Comment: Just verified that the file is there, it is, I edited my original post to reflect the addition of plugin_dir_path, still having the same problem.

Comment: The CSV file is 196 bytes.

Comment: Well have you tried that the code actually runs correctly? copy the function in a separate file as a new project (localhost) and just run the function. If it doesn't work then its something wrong with the php code because the shortcode looks fine.

Comment: Ok, I just tested the php code locally and on PHPfiddle, it runs fine. I also tested the plugin on a fresh wordpress install on another server and I am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Well i tried executing the code and had the same issue, dont know how you were able to execute it without errors. With the first thought in mind, just removed fopen and added the name of the csv file instead of the $handle and everything was fine. So just remove the fopen statement and directly give the file name to the fgetcsv function

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that I edited the php script to work in phpfiddle, meaning I added the CSV file directly to the script, and it worked fine. 

I will try your suggestion.